# Why does IEqualityComparer<T> Equals method take two arguments?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, clr

I don't understand why does the Equals method take (T x, T y). Don't you already have one instance to compare to when you invoke the method on an instance? Same for GetHashCode - why does it need an object instance as a parameter if I'm already invoking it on an existing instance?

What would happen if I invoke a.GetHashCode(b)? Which one is used?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `IEqualityComparer<T>` interface is for a *comparer* object. So, no...you would not already have one instance as part of the implementation.

You may be thinking of `IEquatable<T>`, where it's implemented by the type of object being compared.

Comment: Duh. I was totally thinking of IEquatable Thanks!